# How to handle validations from trigger to show as exception or toast on managed package layout

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, validation, exception, string

I currently have a custom pagelayout from a managed package. In this pagelayout a list of records can be selected to create new records for another object. I have a before apex trigger in which I want to validate some custom fields which are not part of the managed package for the new records.

I want to show my validations before exceptions.

I cant add a lightning component to that pagelayout to catch the validations/exceptions since its managed.

Currently I can throw an error as follows:

```
throw new applicationException(m);
```

But the result message is ugly since I want to show a list of records and the validations they failed with a brakeline. This is the current result:

```
JobApplicationTrigger: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: JobApplicationTriggerHandler.applicationException: <br/>ERROR: Please have a look a following Candidates and/or Jobs. <br/>Jobtest has not the status ready. <br/>Candidate: Candidatetest GDPR status is not approved<br/> ()
Error is in expression '{!create}' in component <apex:commandButton>
```

I also tried to redirect the user to an url where I would display the validation error(s) but this does not work as follows:

```
  ..     
public JobApplicationTriggerHandler(){
        }
    
         public static PageReference redirectToPage(){
    
          PageReference retURL = new PageReference('https://www.google.com/');
          retURL.setRedirect(true);
          return retURL;
    
     }
..





@AuraEnabled
    public static void beforeInsert(List<application__c> newList){
..
if (result == true){  
 
redirectToPage();
 throw new applicationException(m);
}
..
}
```

1. Can I add breaklines to the applicationException?
2. If not how can I redirect the user to another page/lightning component to show the missed validations

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try to use "addError" method in before trigger? Then page message is a bit more user-friendly?

Comment: @kurunve can you assign this to a custom lightning app page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redirectToPage method does nothing, as it doesn't return the PageReference back to the client. Further, you can't both throw an exception and return a value. In addition, you should be throwing an AuraHandledException if that's your intent; ApplicationException isn't a standard Exception for Lightning components.

> Can I add breaklines to the applicationException?

No, the errors will have their whitespace collapse, so it's impossible to make those line breaks work as you expect.

> If not how can I redirect the user to another page/lightning component to show the missed validations

The actual process would involve something like:

```
Map<Integer, String> errors = new Map<Integer, String>();
Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(newList, false);
for(Integer index = 0; index < results.size(); index++) {
    if(!results[index].isSuccess()) {
        errors.put(index, results[index].getErrors()[0].getMessage());
    }
}
if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
    throw new AuraHandledException(JSON.serialize(errors));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I dont get is how do I pass the  AuraHandledException to the lightning component since I cannot add a lightning component to the managed package page.

Comment: @Thomas Not sure what you're asking. If you throw an exception, the component that started the transaction will catch the error.